# NextJS - only run getInitialProps if route is different

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm setting up a NextJS app using `getInitialProps` to pull misc data that I would like to be server-side-rendered on first page load. All is working fine, but I noticed that if I click the same link twice, `getInitialProps` runs again, even though everything is the same.

For example I have a left nav with links to various categories etc (this app is going to be a front-end for an ecommerce site). If I click to a category, the category component (page) loads just fine. Then if I click the exact same link, the `getInitialProps` of the category component runs again, causing the page to blank out for a second while the same data (the item list) is fetched and re-rendered.

So is there a way to prevent `getInitialProps` from running if the user clicks the same link twice?

Note that I'm using `getInitialProps` for two reasons:

1. `getStaticProps` is out because I don't plan to build the entire site at build time
2. `getServerSideProps` is *usually* out because I don't like that it ends up doing two http requests: first a request goes to the `NextJS` server, then the server sends a request to my API (which happens to live on a different server). I'd rather skip the middle man

Some code:

```
Category.getInitialProps = async (context) => {
    let config = await import("../../config/config");

    let response = await axios.get(`${config.default.apiEndpoint}&cAction=getCTGY&ctgyCode=${context.query.code}`);
    let queryString = {...context.query};

    if ( response ) {
        return {
            category: response.data,
            queryString: queryString,
            pathname: context.asPath
        };
    } else {
        return {
            category: null
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Are you running the development or production build?

Comment: development, testing locally, is that why?

Comment: There is a way to get it to cache in the browser (so it never sends the second request to the server) but I'm also wondering if `getInitialProps` is the most suitable. Does `getInitialProps` depend on the incoming request (query parameters, path paramets etc)? Could you add it to the question if it isn't too large?

Comment: ok I added some code and an explanation about why `getInitialProps` is being used, but I'm open to suggestions of course! Oh and yes, it does use query params

Comment: Look into [shallow routing](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/shallow-routing), this also works on [`<Link />` components](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/link). I think this will prevent re-fetching in your use case. Do read the cavet in the documentation though

Comment: That worked, I didn't realize you could use shallow routing on `Link` as well, thanks! I did have to add a `useEffect` inside the category component that monitors the router's category code, and on change I re-fetch category data. Anyway, if you want to add that as an answer I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should Look into [shallow routing](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/shallow-routing) which enables you to change the URL of the page without re-running the data fetching. This includes `getInitialProps`.

Shallow routing also works on `<Link />` components.

```js
<Link href="/" shallow>
    <a>Home</a>
</Link>
```

You should be aware of the caveats though, they're [documented here](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/shallow-routing).